# Facebook iOS SDK: Post to Wall dialog not closing on CANCEL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I am working with Facebook sharing SDK for iPad app. I had used tutorial referenced here:

[iCodeBlog Facebook Tutorial - http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/28/facebook-sdk-posting-to-user-news-feed/](http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/28/facebook-sdk-posting-to-user-news-feed/)

With this tutorial sharing was working perfectly. But It was not showing POST TO WALL dialog, which previews user and asks for any comments before posting story.

I had modified few files and methods, in the manner FBDialog gets displayed.
Now for the POST TO WALL dialog, I am setting everything and it works perfect, when I click on SHARE button in the dialog. But then it shows blank dialog box. And when I tap on CANCEL button it does nothing, after 2-3 more taps dialog box closes.

Can anyone look into following method of FBDialog.m..?

```
webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
    navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

I need Dialog should be closed after SHARE or CANCEL clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my problem is solved. But I had used GET method instead of POST.
In the starting, I was using POST method to pass arguments for POST TO WALL diaglog. I now used GET method now and Passed arguments like this,

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?link=http://www.google.com&description=SAR2011DE&type=link&message=Any%20Comments&name=Investis&picture=http://www.google.com/cover.jpg&access_token=thetoken&redirect_uri=fbconnect://success&display=touch

This link might not work, but mainly I have used following Dictionary and used as get params:

```
[params setObject:@"link" forKey:@"type"];
[params setObject:self.url forKey:@"link"];
[params setObject:self.imagePath forKey:@"picture"];
[params setObject:@"Comment:" forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:self.caption forKey:@"description"];
//[params setObject:self.url forKey:@"caption"];
[params setObject:self.url forKey:@"name"];
[params setValue:[[ResourceHelper sharedHelper] FacebookAPIKey] forKey: @"app_id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial for Facebook Posting on iCodeBlog is using older Api methods of Facebook SDK..

The API for Facebook has been updated..so support for older methods and troubleshooting will be less..

I suggest you implement their latest SDK into your project..
The official tutorial/steps can be found [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/)
It won't take more than 20 minutes to integrate it and tutorial is good.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I found that POST TO WALL dialog is not closed after clicking on SHARE and also CANCEL does nothing. I need to close the Dialog on click of CANCEL or SHARE. SHARE closes dialog and publish story but CANCEL just dismisses dialog.